# angularJS land on specific path and stay there

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

I have an angularJS frontend and I want to redirect my users to an external payments processor and then back (e.g. www.mysite.com/purchase/152398978981/success). 
What works: I pass a redirect URL to the payments processor and get redirected back to that.

What does not work: When getting redirected back, the angularJS app needs to load and upon completion goes to the default/welcome page.

If afterwards, I paste the redirect URL into the address bar everything works fine, because the app has already loaded.

Is there a way to stay on the redirect url even if the app needs to load?

EDIT:

This is an abbreviated version of how I do the routing. The route in question is the last one before 'otherwise' i.e. when('/sofort/:websafeProductKey')

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',
    ['productControllers', 'ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'firebase', 'ngTouch', 'ngResource']).config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/product/create', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/create_product.html',
            controller: 'CreateProductCtrl'
        }).when('/product/detail/:websafeProductKey', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/product_detail.html',
            controller: 'ProductDetailCtrl'
        }).when('/checkout', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/paymill.html'
        }).when('/landing/', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/landing.html'
        }).when('/auth', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/auth.html'
        }).when('/sofort/:websafeProductKey', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/sofort_success.html',
            controller: 'SofortCtrl'
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/landing'
        });
    }]);
```

This is how I load the Google API, I wrote:

```
<script>
        /**
         * Initializes the Google API JavaScript client. Bootstrap the angular module after loading the Google libraries
         * so that Google JavaScript library ready in the angular modules.
         */
        function callGoogleApis() {
            // Loads the goal APIs asynchronously
            var apisToLoad;
            var googleCallback = function () {
                if (--apisToLoad == 0) {
                    //Manual bootstraping of the application
                    var $injector = angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]);
                    console.log("myApp bootstrap complete " + gapi);
                }
            };

            apisToLoad = 1; // must match number of apis to load - currently a bit redundant
            gapi.client.load('myApi', 'v1', googleCallback, '//' + window.location.host + '/_ah/api');
        }
    </script>
    <script src="//apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js?onload=callGoogleApis"></script>
```

Comment: can you show how you do the routing (`angular.config` code)

Comment: added it above - I am using the default router. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "redirect URL", what does it look like or what does it do exactly? Also I don't understand why angularjs _needs to load_, when it's always loaded as it's a SPA (you never refresh the page). As an alternative to `ngRoute` there is also `ui.router` (better/flexible option)

Comment: Client clicks purchase -> pays on external page in this case sofort.com. Sofort.com redirects back to my page mypage.com/sofort/Database_key -> Client Lands in my page.com/sofort/Database_key but in a new tab. App needs to load in that new window and goes to landing page

Comment: ok, got it. It doesn't matter if angularjs is not pre-loaded, `$routeProvider` should handle the routing for you (unless you have _html5mode_ on). Does your URL fit the requirement `.when('/sofort/:websafeProductKey'` ? Because if it fails to do that, then it will redirect on `.otherwise(...` call

Comment: If I have the app loaded in a tab and paste a redirect url (i.e. /sofort/dbkey) into the address bar - that works fine. Only in the real world case when the tab is opened from sofort.com it loads and goes to landing. That is why I concluded it might have been the loading that messed up the routing

Comment: I thought it might have been that the app is slow to recognize log in status and that is the reason for redirect (because only a logged in user can pay). So I turned that off for testing. Still happens...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164812/discussion-between-aleksey-solovey-and-sllegendre).